# Rails: Filtering list of objects with another object (has_many through)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an object Contact that has_many sectors through bridge-object ContactSector. I have a form on the contact index page where I currently filter the contact list by simple strings.

I would like to have a list of checkboxes for sectors, and @contacts only returns a list of contacts with the chosen sectors. It doesn't have to match all of them, at least one.

**Models**

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Filterable

  scope :firstname, -> (firstname) { where("firstname like ?", "#{firstname}%")}
  scope :lastname, -> (lastname) { where("lastname like ?", "#{lastname}%")}
  scope :title, -> (title) { where("title like ?", "#{title}%")}
  scope :sectors, -> (sector) {where("sector like ?", "#{sector}%")} #Attempt

  has_many :sectors, through: :contact_sectors
  has_many :contact_sectors

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sectors
end

class ContactSector < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :sector
end

class Sector < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts, :through => :contact_sectors
  has_many :contact_sectors
end
```

**filterable.rb**

```
module Filterable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def filter(filtering_params)
      results = self.where(nil)
      filtering_params.each do |key, value|
        results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
      end
      results
    end
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_tag '', :method => :get do %>
    <label>Sectors</label><br>
    <% Sector.all.each do |sector| %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'sector_ids[]', '' %>
        <%= check_box_tag 'sector_ids[]', sector.id %>
        <%= sector.sector %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
def index
    @contacts = Contact.filter(params.slice(:firstname, sector_ids: [])
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Model**

```
class Sector < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :contacts, :through => :contact_sectors
    has_many :contact_sectors
    def name_with_initial
        "#{sector}"
    end
end
```

**View**

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:sector, :ids, Sector.all, :id, :name_with_initial) do |b| %>
    <%= b.label do %>
        <%= b.check_box %>
        <%= b.text %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
def index
    @contacts = Contact.filter(params.slice(:firstname) #Or just Contact.all
    @filter = params[:sector][:ids]
    @filter.shift #First array entry is always a blank string
    unless @filter.to_a.empty?
        @contacts = @contacts.includes(:sectors).references(:sectors).where('sectors.id IN (?)', @filter)
    end
end
```

I do multiple sorts with a list of various categories so I made this function to iterate the filter using a provided string array:

```
  def filtercontacts(filters)
    filters.each {
        |x|
      if eval('params[:' + x + ']')!=nil
        @filter = eval('params[:'+ x +'][:ids]')
        @filter.shift
      end
      unless @filter.to_a.empty?
        @contacts = @contacts.includes(eval(':'+x.pluralize)).references(eval(':'+x.pluralize)).where(eval('\''+ x.pluralize+'.id IN (?)\''), @filter)
        @filter = []
      end
    }
    @contacts
  end
```

And then use like so

```
@contacts = filtercontacts(Array['area', 'art', 'category', 'demographic', 'donation_type', 'education', 'project', 'sector', 'support'])
```